# laravel 6 api route 404

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route in my laravel app like this,

`Route::post('/user', 'UserController@create');`

Running `php artisan route:list` returns,

```
|        | POST     | api/user                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                 | api                                             |
```

The test I have for this method/route passes, however if I run a POST via postman I get a 404 error, any ideas why?

This is the cURL request that POST man generates.

```
curl -X POST \
  http://server.test/api/user \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: f15f811c-9b0c-48aa-83c7-5920a86b313a,aee37d37-4596-43ea-9c7d-ed4b5f406fed' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ijl4dzh4MEkwdUF0ZVQ5UXdQV2gwSHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaVN0eXI2TEIwMFhZQXhCOVFzR1wvakxFN0NQOENYRTNqRk54VWhCRDg1VHhhSlVmQitsR0lta2ltUGZnbWpJZDUiLCJtYWMiOiI1ODc0ZTE0MmU1YTRiNTcxY2UzZTI2ODdjNmJhMzdiMTkzODQ4NDJmNzFhZGQ4YjRhNjljNDQzNDE4YWFjZDlmIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ill0OENYUXRaY21PVzFBMUtrMjVtblE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSTA0VVZOV3FMQXlYWndhQ3RhV0pNK052VVpEN0MrZ3dkeHRYOVp6UnhzUktyeUxCWHhqS1JzMnlZU29UZjZlYSIsIm1hYyI6IjkxMDI0ZmQwYjQyZDIzNjFmMWNmZTkxN2UzMTFkMzU2MWU2MTY4ODAwYWUzZWI1NjQ3NGEwNjg4Yjk3NDk4YWUifQ%3D%3D' \
  -H 'referer: http://server.test/api/user' \
  -b 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ijl4dzh4MEkwdUF0ZVQ5UXdQV2gwSHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaVN0eXI2TEIwMFhZQXhCOVFzR1wvakxFN0NQOENYRTNqRk54VWhCRDg1VHhhSlVmQitsR0lta2ltUGZnbWpJZDUiLCJtYWMiOiI1ODc0ZTE0MmU1YTRiNTcxY2UzZTI2ODdjNmJhMzdiMTkzODQ4NDJmNzFhZGQ4YjRhNjljNDQzNDE4YWFjZDlmIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ill0OENYUXRaY21PVzFBMUtrMjVtblE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSTA0VVZOV3FMQXlYWndhQ3RhV0pNK052VVpEN0MrZ3dkeHRYOVp6UnhzUktyeUxCWHhqS1JzMnlZU29UZjZlYSIsIm1hYyI6IjkxMDI0ZmQwYjQyZDIzNjFmMWNmZTkxN2UzMTFkMzU2MWU2MTY4ODAwYWUzZWI1NjQ3NGEwNjg4Yjk3NDk4YWUifQ%3D%3D'
```

Comment: Info about your environment? What webserver? Other routes works? Are you using the right method on postman?

Comment: can you include your actual postman test request

Comment: have a look at your laravel.log file. it might have a stack trace of what the actual error is

Comment: @EliasSoares routes that use closures work fine. I am using Laravel Valet as my web server.

Comment: @usrNotFound no stack trace so not a webserver or PHP error I am lead to believe.

Comment: What's your `UserController@create` definition like?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your .htaccess file block your request which locate in public folder. I have similar issue for this, then i rewrite my .htaccess like this below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`</IfModule>`

Maybe this help you